# Activity crash caused by fragment on item click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I click on my button "btn_search" after having selected the item "DEF", my application crash and I don't know how to fix that.

Thank for your help and sorry for my english, I'm French.

**My Code (MenuDocumentation)**

```
package ssip.ssip;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuDocumentation extends Fragment {

    View rootview;
    private Button btn_search;

    ArrayAdapter adapterSpinner_1;
    Spinner spin1;
    String spn_1_Selected_item;
    String[] spinn_marque = {"Veuillez choisir une marque","DEF"};
    TextView txtdocumentation;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu_documentation, container, false);

        btn_search = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        spin1 = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.spin1);
        txtdocumentation = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtdocumentation);

        adapterSpinner_1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinn_marque);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_1);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spn_1_Selected_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                if (spn_1_Selected_item.equals("Veuillez choisir une marque"))
                    txtdocumentation.setText("");

                if (spn_1_Selected_item.equals("DEF"))
                    btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DocumentationDef.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

**My code (DocumentationDef)**

```
package ssip.ssip;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DocumentationDef extends Fragment {

    View rootview;
    private Button btn_search;

    ArrayAdapter adapterSpinner_1;
    Spinner spin1;
    String spn_1_Selected_item;
    String[] spinn_element = {"Veuillez choisir un élément","RAPPORT ASSOCIATION"};
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_documentation_def, container, false);

        btn_search = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
        spin1 = (Spinner) rootview.findViewById(R.id.spin1);
        tv1 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        adapterSpinner_1 = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinn_element);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapterSpinner_1);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spn_1_Selected_item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                if (spn_1_Selected_item.equals("Veuillez choisir un élément"))
                    tv1.setText("");
                    tv2.setText("");

                if (spn_1_Selected_item.equals("RAPPORT ASSOCIATION")){
                    tv1.setText("FORTE S");
                    tv2.setText("RAPPORT");
                    btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String url = "http://google.fr";
                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

**My Logcat**

```
09-25 20:07:28.965 23029-23029/ssip.ssip D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
09-25 20:07:29.045 23029-23029/ssip.ssip D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
09-25 20:07:29.045 23029-23029/ssip.ssip I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:ssip.ssip time:78837586
09-25 20:07:29.075 23029-23029/ssip.ssip D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-25 20:07:29.085 23029-23029/ssip.ssip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ssip.ssip, PID: 23029
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ssip.ssip/ssip.ssip.DocumentationDef}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ssip.ssip.DocumentationDef cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: ssip.ssip.DocumentationDef cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3084)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**SOLUTION**

```
if (spn_1_Selected_item.equals("DEF"))
                    btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            DocumentationDef DocumentationDef = new DocumentationDef();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, DocumentationDef);
                            transaction.commit();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It's the class where I want to go.
If I select "DEF" and click on "btn_search", he load the class "DocumentationDef".

Comment: I update my post. No, He extend fragment. I think the problem is here but I can't remove the "extend fragment". I try to change Activity and Fragment but he don't work.

Comment: DocumentationDef2 isa fragment.  You can't launch a fragment like an Activity.  You need to write an Activity which includes the Fragment.

Comment: Please post the DocumentationDef class. Also you need to do some research about the differences between activities and fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentationDef2 is a fragment as it extends a fragment. 
Your code of 
new Intent(getActivity(), DocumentationDef.class); will not work.
Use FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions to replace the MenuDocumentation fragment with DocumentationDef2. Or create a new activity DocumentationDefActivity and place the fragment in the DocumentationDefActivity

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much :) I've post solution in my first post.